# Model Binding in Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

For some reason I cannot get NancyFx to bind to my model for a web page. I am self hosting with this if that matters.

Here is my route code:

```
Get["/fax.html"] = p =>
{
    FaxModel model = new FaxModel();

    var foundType = processes.Where(proc => proc.GetType().ToString().Contains("FaxServer"));
    if(foundType.First() != null)
    {
        bool enabled = Boolean.Parse(WorkflowSettings.GetValue(foundType.First().GetProcessName(), "Enabled"));
        bool deleteAfterSuccess = Boolean.Parse(WorkflowSettings.GetValue(foundType.First().GetProcessName(), "DeleteWorkflowItemsAfterSuccess"));

        model.EnableFaxes = enabled;
        model.DeleteFaxes = deleteAfterSuccess;

        // Bind the data
        this.BindTo<FaxModel>(model);
    }

    return View["fax.html"];
};
```

Here is my model:

```
[Serializable]
public class FaxModel
{
    public bool EnableFaxes { get; set; }
    public bool DeleteFaxes { get; set; }
}
```

Now here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="body">
  <form method="post" action="fax.html" name="fax_settings">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input name="EnableFaxes" value="true" type="checkbox">Automated Faxing Enabled
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="margin-left: 80px;"><input name="DeleteFaxes" value="true" type="checkbox">Delete workflow items when fax is successful</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button name="Save">Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am unable to see why it is not populating these checkboxes at all. Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the settings with BindTo. Remove that call and return a view with parameter.

`this.Bind` and `this.BindTo` are used to bind input parameters (query, form, request body) to a model, not to bind data to a view.

```
Get["fax"] = p =>
{
    FaxModel model = new FaxModel();

    var foundType = processes.Where(proc => proc.GetType().ToString().Contains("FaxServer"));
    if(foundType.First() != null)
    {
        bool enabled = Boolean.Parse(WorkflowSettings.GetValue(foundType.First().GetProcessName(), "Enabled"));
        bool deleteAfterSuccess = Boolean.Parse(WorkflowSettings.GetValue(foundType.First().GetProcessName(), "DeleteWorkflowItemsAfterSuccess"));

        model.EnableFaxes = enabled;
        model.DeleteFaxes = deleteAfterSuccess;
    }

    return View["fax", model];
};
```

Or, as far as your model class follows the convention, you can just do:

```
return View[model];
```

See the [view engine examples](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-engines).

Also, your html should use the model properties like this:

```
<input name="EnableFaxes" value=@Model.EnableFaxes type="checkbox">Automated Faxing Enabled
```

Comment: Neither of those seem to work. Changed my code to be what you posted. Verified the database to make sure I have a true and false on the model values respectively and when I do a complete rebuild then run it does not show either checked.

Comment: It will not work as you have it. It's a static html, there is no way it can replace the parameters. You need some view engine. Look at the link with examples I provided.

Comment: That worked as soon as I put in the data from the engine. The documentation doesn't really defined binding on this which threw me off. Thanks a bunch!